# Firefox cuts the end of words when printing Bootstrap + Google Fonts

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox, printing, bootstrap-4, google-fonts

I want to print a webpage in Firefox (last version). I am using Bootstrap and Google Fonts.
Most time this works very well, but somethimes (mostly on a Mac (2/2) less often on Windows (1/5) Firefox cuts off the end of words or overlaps them

If you inspect a pdf printed page in Adobe Illustrator it looks like this:

[image]

So text is complete but the end is hidden.

Here is an example page: https://western-gray.glitch.me/

Just print this page in a pdf. (Print preview loks fine, even if printing is wrong.)

I have no clue what to do. I spent eight hours today looking for the error. I'd be grateful for some advice

Answer (score 0):

We removed https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lora from our project and we got more wirking Firefox Browsers. So If you have an similar problem, try to remove your font, meybe they are corrupted.